# Why does openpyxl take forever to import in django?

Tags: python, django, pandas, numpy, openpyxl

I'm writing (or attempting to write) views to handle importing and exporting xlsx files, but the statement `import openpyxl` never finishes execution in my view (or anywhere else in my Django application). If I run it from `./manage.py shell` it works fine—takes a half-second or so, but works.

My view is as follows, stripped to barebones to make sure there's nothing weird to interfere:

```
def test_view(request):
    import openpyxl
    return HttpResponse('Testing')
```

and the view never loads. I get rid of (comment out) the one line, it works. Same behavior if I try importing at the top of `views.py`, except then the problem applies to every view. Even if I try to load a subset, like `from openpyxl import Workbook`, or `from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook` as suggested [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/openpyxl-users/T6JqLPkYB4c/JPppUNQVphsJ), same deal.

Pertinent info:

- openpyxl 2.4.2
- django 1.10.2
- python 3.4.3
- pandas 0.19.2
- numpy 1.12.0

Any ideas as to what's happening? Any way I can perhaps get an error message to show up to tell me what's going on?

---

One way to "fix" the issue ***but it's not a real fix*** is by changing the line

```
_eps = np.finfo('f4').eps
```

to

```
_eps = 1.1920929e-07
```

in `pandas.core.indexing`. Though the number given seems to be the case for the particular machines I'm using, and may be a common number, I know this is a *terrible* idea, so I'm still looking for a better solution.

***Updated 2017-02-17T07:05:*** *Added/updated version numbers of packages, added everything below the `<hr />`*

Comment: Have you already tested the import in `shell_plus`?

Comment: `shell_plus` doesn't work with django 1.10, at least not out of the box. After doing what it does, though, from the normal django shell, it takes longer, but still imports fine.

Comment: The only IO that `openpyxl` does at startup is to read and open a json file called `.constants.json`.  It’s a very small file, so I suspect that there might either be other issues with its subsidiary imports.  It also tries to import numpy and pandas at import, IIRC.

Comment: I've chased the line down to the following statement in `pandas.core.indexing`:

`_eps = np.finfo('f4').eps`

This still works fine in my python shell, but doesn't work in django. I'm going to try updating my packages, see if this "error" has been fixed in more recent versions of numpy and/or pandas.

Comment: Nope, still a problem. I put `a=b` before that line, I get the error I expect. After that line, I get infinite loading time.